# Windows Universal App Development Shutdown Timer Possible?

Tags: c#, windows, shutdown, universal

Is there a way to shut down the device by calling a method in c#? And if yes, an example would be nice. Be aware of that i'm asking if it's possible in a **windows universal app**.

Comment: I think you need to do some research on this first and show what you've tried.

Comment: @tnw yeah and that's why i'm asking in this forum because I found nothing related to this topic except how to shut down a pc by calling a c# function but I don't know if it is possible to do this with a universal application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can NOT shut down the device with a windows universal app.

Comment: (but you maybe can setup a connection between a desktop app (background progress to shut down) and universal app, server usage maybe)